# Android: preferred way to create a listener, function vs inner class vs object

Tags: android, kotlin, listener, android-mvvm

Currently, I am creating a simple `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` inside my fragment. My problem is, that I have three ways to create it:

### Solution 1

```
fun switchListener() : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    return CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) rebuildViewModel
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

```
inner class SwitchClass : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) rebuildViewModel
    }
}
```

### Solution 3

```
object SwitchListener : CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    override fun onCheckedChanged(buttonView: CompoundButton?, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if(isChecked) rebuildViewModel // unresolved reference
    }
}
```

My question is, what are the major differences between those implementations? The only difference I see is that `rebuildViewModel` is not accessible inside my `object SwitchListener`. Why is that so? What implementation should I prefer?

Comment: `object` is (essentially) static, it's already an instance, so yes, it can't access something not declared inside itself

Comment: So `solution 3` is not possible at all? I thought `object` would be a static instance inside my `fragment class` and therefore could access everything inside my fragment

Comment: Some guidance on best practice would be appreciated!